# Postfix reject_rbl_client: client or recipient restriction?

Tags: postfix, smtp

[This](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix_restrictions) and [this](https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/349.html) say the `reject_rbl_client` is a `smtpd_recipient_restriction`. However, the [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_rbl_client) show it's only a `smtpd_client_restriction`, which makes sense to me. So, which is it?

Also, why when I configure nonsense, `postfix check` and `service postfix reload` just accept it?

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_rbl_cliena bl.spamcop.net
```

And:

```
root@server: /etc/postfix # postfix check
root@server: /etc/postfix # echo $?
0
root@server: /etc/postfix #
```

And:

```
# service postfix reload
Reloading Postfix configuration...done.
```

Version: 2.9.6-2
Debian 7 (Wheezy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you scroll down to the end of [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) in the Postfix documentation, it explains that SMTP command specific restrictions for **client**, **helo** and **sender** are also valid in the **sender** context. In other words: you may put the `reject_rbl_client` restriction in either list.

When receiving mail, Postfix wil apply the `smtpd_*_restrictions` in this order: **client**, **helo**, **sender**, **relay**, **recipient**, **data** and **end_of_data**. When a restriction evaluates to `REJECT` or `DEFER`, the restrictions that follow are skipped. Ideally the fast and cheap checks are done first, so that you can skip relatively expensive checks (like looking up an external blacklist) most of the time. By moving the `reject_rbl_client` value out of the `smtpd_client_restrictions` and into the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, you will decrease the number of times Postfix needs to look up that blacklist.

The `postfix check` will complain about a typo in the name of your parameter, but not about a typo in the value of the parameter (as was your case). Quoting a [post](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Postfix-config-check-command-td76742.html) by the Postfix author (Wietse Venema):

> In many cases, the syntax of the 1000+ parameter values is checked
>   only when a value is used.  For example, the syntax of the mynetworks
>   value is checked only when a specific IP address is matched against
>   this list (and if the syntax error is at the end of the list, it may
>   yaake a while before the error is noticed).